# Trasform sql query in xml file with child node in the same row

Tags: sql, xml

I want to ask you if it's possible with a Sql query when i got a table like this

[Img_Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feu6a.png)

have an xml output like that:

```
<Yarn>

<YCode>ACRILINO-1x16</YCode>

<YName>Filato</YName>

<YCount countUnit="Nm">16.00</YCount>

<Ply>1</Ply>

<TwistSense>0</TwistSense>

<Twists lengthUnit="m">222</Twists>

<TwistContraction>0.0</TwistContraction>

<Model>0</Model>

<DimensionFactor>13</DimensionFactor>


-<Fibre>

<Fibre percentage="80">pc</Fibre>

<Fibre percentage="20">li</Fibre>

</Fibre>

</Yarn>
```

If you see i've the Percentage in the same row, there's a way to do it?

```
    select ycode,yname,'Nm' as 'YCount/@CountUnit', Ycount,comp1,
case  /*comp1*/
    when  CHARINDEX('%',Comp1)= 0 then LEN(Comp1) 
    else LEFT(Comp1,CHARINDEX('%',Comp1)-1) 
end as 'Fibre/@Percentage',
case  /* Comp2 */
    when  CHARINDEX('%',Comp2)= 0 then LEN(Comp2) 
    else LEFT(Comp2,CHARINDEX('%',Comp2)-1) 
end as 'Fibre/@Percentage',
case
    when CHARINDEX('%',Comp1)= 0 then ''
    else right(Comp1,CHARINDEX('%',Reverse(Comp1))-1) 
end as Fibre,
case
    when CHARINDEX('%',Comp2)= 0 then ''
    else right(Comp2,CHARINDEX('%',Reverse(Comp2))-1) 
end as Fibre
from FILATIXML f
where ycode='AC501'
```

for xml path ('Yarn')

but i got this error:

```
Column name 'Fibre/@Percentage' is repeated. The same attribute cannot be generated more than once on the same XML tag.
```

**The problem is how can i've multiple child with the same tag with different fields?**

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
First of all Thanks to all of you.

```
select ycode,yname,'Nm' as 'YCount/@CountUnit', Ycount,
case 
    when  CHARINDEX('%',Comp1)= 0 then LEN(Comp1) /* COMPOSIZIONE 1 */
    else LEFT(Comp1,CHARINDEX('%',Comp1)-1) end as [Fibre/@percentage],
case
    when CHARINDEX('%',Comp1)= 0 then ''        
    else right(Comp1,CHARINDEX('%',Reverse(Comp1))-1) 
    end as [Fibre],
case 
    when  CHARINDEX('%',Comp2)= 0 then LEN(Comp1) /* COMPOSIZIONE 1 */
    else LEFT(Comp2,CHARINDEX('%',Comp2)-1) end as [Fibre/@percentage],
case
    when CHARINDEX('%',Comp2)= 0 then ''        
    else right(Comp2,CHARINDEX('%',Reverse(Comp2))-1) 
    end as [Fibre]
from 
filatixml
where ycode='AC001'
for xml path('z')
```

If i select only Comp1 it works perfect, but if i add the case to select comp2 It gives me this error:
*

> Attribute-centric column 'Fibre/@percentage' must not come after a
> non-attribute-centric sibling in XML hierarchy in FOR XML PATH.

- 

I can't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please post sample data as text, not image.

Comment: What is your database: SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, etc.?

Comment: My Database is sql. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can build the `fibre` nodes as xml. Demo

```
with tbl as (
  select 1 id, 'a' c1, 20 p1, 'b' c2, 80 p2 
)    
select id, 
    cast((select p1 [fibre/@percentage], c1 fibre for xml path('')) as xml),
    cast((select p2 [fibre/@percentage], c2 fibre for xml path('')) as xml)
from tbl
for xml path('z');
```

Returns

```
<z> 
  <id>1</id>
  <fibre percentage="20">a</fibre>
  <fibre percentage="80">b</fibre>
</z>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea like @Serg just simpler and more performant.

**SQL**

```
WITH tbl AS 
(
  SELECT 1 id, 'a' c1, 20 p1, 'b' c2, 80 p2 
)    
SELECT id
    , p1 [fibre/@percentage], c1 AS fibre
    , NULL
    , p2 [fibre/@percentage], c2 AS fibre
FROM tbl
FOR XML PATH('z'), TYPE;
```

**Output**

```
<z>
  <id>1</id>
  <fibre percentage="20">a</fibre>
  <fibre percentage="80">b</fibre>
</z>
```